# Bootstrap Carousel with 3 objects Django implementation

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, bootstrap-carousel, bootstrap-studio

I need a carousel displaying 3 team-member objects per slide.

```
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    {% for m in memb %}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                        {% else %}
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                        {% endif %}
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member"><img class="rounded-circle mx-auto" src="{{ m.image1.url }}">
                                        <h4>{{ m.name1 }}</h4>
                                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#{{ m.facebook1 }}"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#{{ m.instagram1 }}"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member"><img class="rounded-circle mx-auto" src="{{ m.image2.url }}">
                                        <h4>{{ m.name2 }}</h4>
                                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#{{ m.facebook2 }}"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#{{ m.instagram2 }}"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="team-member"><img class="rounded-circle mx-auto" src="{{ m.image3.url }}">
                                        <h4>{{ m.name3 }}</h4>
                                        <ul class="list-inline social-buttons" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#{{ m.facebook3 }}"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#{{ m.instagram3 }}"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div><a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-3" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="width: 50px;"><span class="carousel-control-prev-icon border rounded-circle" style="background-color: #000000;"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
                    <a
                        class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-3" role="button" data-slide="next" style="width: 50px;"><span class="carousel-control-next-icon border rounded-circle" style="background-color: #000000;"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
                </div>
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-3" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-3" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-3" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I was unable to figure out how to dynamically create 1 item so I added 3 variables of each (image1,image2,image3,etc.)

**The main problem is my controls don't work.**

The 2nd problem is that I have to keep adding objects in pairs of 3 else it doesn't work.
I can't seem to find any proper solutions to this online.

Comment: Usually to make a carousel, I create an inner template **slide** that I include in a loop. It's more clear. You must include your controls in the loop too. See here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/